# Элементы фрагмента заходят за action bar

Tags: android, android-fragment, actionbar

Когда запускаю приложение на эмуляторе, элементы заходят за границы видимого экрана, как будто нет "шторки" телефона и action bar'а. [image: отображение элементов]

Что нужно изменить, чтобы элементы не заходили и отображались ниже action bar'а?

Answer (score 0):

нашла проблему
я забыла убрать из layout'а активити элементы для навигационного меню, которое не использовала больше